# switch case with string in c++

Tags: c++, string, enums

I want to write a switch case with string. I used enum and I write this:

> ```
>  string enum {
>     next  = 0,
>     prev  = 1,
>     ext   = 2
>     }order;
> ```

```
  while(true)
  {
      cin >> order;
      switch(order)
      {
        case 0:
            //do order0
            break;
        case 1 :
            //do order 1
            break;
        case 2 :
           //do order2
            return;
            break;
        default: 
            cout << "Bad input";
            break;
    }
}
```

but the result is this error:

> error C2236: unexpected token 'enum'. Did you forget a ';'?

what's the reason of this error?

is there any other way to write a switch with string?

Comment: what is `string enum` ?

Comment: @PiotrS.I just saw an example like this.

Comment: `string` is a class, `enum` is a reserved keyword. The compiler probably thinks that you're trying to instantiate a `string` object with the name "enum", so it expects a `;` (or an assignment and then a `;`) immediately after.

Comment: @zahra could you show us where you saw this example? I'm still baffled by the 'string enum ...'

Comment: @AtlasC1 here : [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/85478/)

Comment: That just goes to show you can't always trust code you find on programming forums. At least here, code like that would get downvoted into oblivion pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't fight the language. You can't switch on strings in C++ as you know.

Use `if`, `else if` instead.

You do see various attempts crop up from time to time. Maps, enums, and hashes being three I can think of. But they just obfuscate. And you'll probably need `break` statements which worsen things further. (If follow through *would* have been useful then structure the equivalent `if` block accordingly).

Your `;` error is due to `string enum` being syntatically invalid.

Comment: I don't recommend using an `if, else if` ladder.  A table lookup with function object, function pointers or conversion data would be easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

What's this :-

```
string enum {
    next  = 0,
    prev  = 1,
    ext   = 2
    }order;
```

It should be:-

```
enum Mydata {
        next  = 0,
        prev  = 1,
        ext   = 2
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from:

```
string enum {
    next  = 0,
    prev  = 1,
    ext   = 2
}order;
```

This is invalid syntax, enum and string are both types and you can't make an instance of a type with another reserved keyword.

Instead you want to declare the enum like this:

```
enum order{
    next  = 0,
    prev  = 1,
    ext   = 2
};
```

But chances are that you really don't want to go about solving your problem in this way. A simple way is just using conditionals with `if` statements or perhaps `std::map` instead.

```
cin >> order;
if(order == "0"){

}else if( order == "1"){

}else{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because'string enum' is not valid.
Here is an example:

```
 enum Orders{
     next=0,
     prev=1,
     ext=2
    };

    while(true)
   {
    int oder=-1;
    cin>>order;
    switch(order)
      {
      case next:
       //do something
        break;
      case prev:
        //do something else
        break;
      case ext:
        //something else
        break;
      default:
        cout << "error\n";
        break;
      }
     }
```